# Modal dialog that disables its parent's menu bar in Racket/GUI?

Tags: user-interface, racket

1. Using racket gui library, I find I can't a real modal dialog that when it's showed, it's impossible to activate its parent window.
2. Although the dialog will block its parent's eventspace, the menu bar in parent window can be clicked, and thus the same dialog can be showed again and again.  Following is the code:

`#lang racket/gui`

```
(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "test"]
                   [width 200]
                   [height 200]))

(define mb (new menu-bar% [parent frame]))

(let ([m (new menu% 
              [parent mb]
              [label "&About"])])
  (new menu-item%
       [parent m]
       [label "&About"]
       [callback (lambda (b e) (message-box "About" "This is a test." frame))])
  )


(send frame show #t)
```

(p.s the message-box can pop up a dialog - the same as `(new dialog% [parent frame])`)

So if we ignores the first question, can we show a modal dialog that disables parent's menu bar?

Besides, is it really impossible to make a real modal dialog in racket/gui?

(I'm working on Win7)

Comment: Good question! You're probably better off asking this question on the mailing list: http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/ , though you might get lucky here.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! I'll ask then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followup: it was a bug, and will be repaired.

References:

1. http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2012-April/051275.html
2. http://git.racket-lang.org/plt/commit/9d563c786a71b621fcd2909c917b49939e0d11b0

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `frame%`, I think you want to use a [`dialog%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/dialog_.html) class here. I'm not sure that you can make a modal dialog that has a menu bar easily though.

Oh, also keep in mind that `dialog%` is only modal for its eventspace. So if you run a code snippet from DrRacket that creates a dialog, then DrRacket itself will still be accessible.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code at first. I've modified it. Now `(message-box "about" "content" frame)` is create a dialog whose parent is the frame.  Run it, and the about messagebox won't disable the menu bar in the frame.

Comment: What platform are you on? On Linux I don't see this behavior (i.e., the menu bar is not clickable). In any case, if it's a platform-specific bug you should send in a bug report.

Comment: I'm working on windows 7. Now I'm sure it's a platform-specific bug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit hackish, but you could do it yourself with  `[callback (lambda (b e) (send mb enable #f) (message-box "About" "This is a test.") (send mb enable #t))]` Or perhaps use `dynamic-wind` if continuations are involved, which in your example they're not.

Comment: Maybe it's a solution. It seems a bug is in racket/gui.